OutOfMemoryError when resizing large images using Thumbnails in Java (Heap Size Limitation)
I'm encountering a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when trying to resize large images using the Thumbnailator Dependency in Springboot. My heap size is limited to -Xms256m -Xmx512m, and I believe the issue arises due to the size of the images being processed.
Below is the code snippet I'm using to resize and compress the images:
   private static void compressImage(File file) throws IOException {
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("temp", ".jpg");
    try {
        Thumbnails.of(file)
                .rotate(0)
                .scale(0.75f)
                .outputQuality(0.9f)
                .outputFormat("jpg")
                .toFile(tempFile.toFile());

        Files.move(tempFile, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } finally {
        Files.deleteIfExists(tempFile);
    }
}

Error Details:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

Maven Dependency

net.coobird
thumbnailator
0.4.20

Heap Size:
-Xms256m -Xmx512m
Questions:

How can I optimize my current approach to handle large image resizing within the given memory constraints?
Is there a better way to handle large image files using the Thumbnails library or any alternative libraries?

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated!

A [mre] is needed.

how large is the file? thumbnailnator specifically says it need width * height * 4 bytes of heap space - see faq.

@BagusTesa - thanks.
file size is 9,206,743 bytes  (width =11812 pixels ,height= 9449 pixels).

have you tried to calculate how much memory it will need? i got ~425MB.
